# Getting Mono to work with Cent OS 5.6

Tags: .net, linux, mono, centos

I'm having a problem in getting Mono to work on my Cent OS 5.6 32-bit web server.

I have a WordPress website that will work in tandem with a .net backend. I followed this guide in getting Mono installed on the server:

http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx

On completion, this was my terminal result:

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/mcs'
Makefile:53: warning: overriding commands for target `csproj-local'
../build/executable.make:134: warning: ignoring old commands for target `csproj-local'
make install-local
make[6]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/mcs'
Makefile:53: warning: overriding commands for target `csproj-local'
../build/executable.make:134: warning: ignoring old commands for target `csproj-local'
/bin/sh ./../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0
/usr/bin/install -c -c -m 755 ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0
test ! -f ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe.mdb || /usr/bin/install -c -c -m 755           ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe.mdb /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0
/usr/bin/install -c -c -m 644 ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe.config   /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0
test ! -f ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe.so || /usr/bin/install -c -c -m 755  ./../class/lib/net_4_0/dmcs.exe.so /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/mcs'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/mcs'
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/docs'
make install-local
make[6]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/docs'
/bin/sh ./../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/lib/monodoc /usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/lib/monodoc /usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources
/usr/bin/install -c -c -m 644 cs-errors.tree cs-errors.zip ecma334.tree ecma334.zip     Mono.tree Mono.zip netdocs.tree netdocs.zip Novell.tree Novell.zip             lang-    csharp.source Mono.source netdocs.source Novell.source /usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources
/usr/bin/install -c -c -m 644 monodoc.xml /usr/local/lib/monodoc
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/docs'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/docs'
make install-local
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/runtime'
Making install in scripts
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/scripts'
Makefile:710: warning: overriding commands for target `mod'
Makefile:690: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mod'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/scripts'
Makefile:710: warning: overriding commands for target `mod'
Makefile:690: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mod'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
/usr/bin/install -c makecert sn al ilasm gacutil mkbundle monop resgen wsdl al2 csharp2   gacutil2 gmcs mdoc monop2 resgen2 wsdl2 mono-service mono-service2 nunit-console nunit-  console2 mono-find-provides mono-find-requires mdoc-assemble mdoc-export-html mdoc-export-  msxdoc mdoc-update mdoc-validate mdassembler mdvalidater monodocer monodocs2html   monodocs2slashdoc mono-test-install peverify mcs mono-heapviz mono-configuration-crypto   dmcs disco '/usr/local/bin'
/usr/bin/install -c dtd2xsd dtd2rng installvst genxs macpack mono-cil-strip prj2make  soapsuds caspol cert2spc certmgr chktrust csharp httpcfg lc mconfig mod monolinker mono- api-info mono-shlib-cop mozroots permview pdb2mdb xsd mono-xmltool setreg secutil signcode  sgen sqlmetal sqlsharp svcutil xbuild ccrewrite '/usr/local/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/scripts'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/scripts'
Making install in man
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/man'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/man'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man1" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/man/man1"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 al.1 cert2spc.1 certmgr.1 chktrust.1 cilc.1 csharp.1 disco.1  dtd2xsd.1 gacutil.1 genxs.1 httpcfg.1 ilasm.1 lc.1 macpack.1 makecert.1 mconfig.1 mcs.1 mdassembler.1 mdoc.1 mdoc-assemble.1 mdoc-export-html.1 mdoc-export-msxdoc.1 mdoc-update.1 mdoc-validate.1 mdvalidater.1 mkbundle.1 mono.1 mprof-report.1 mono-cil-strip.1 monodocer.1 monodocs2html.1 monolinker.1 monop.1 mono-api-info.1 mono-service.1 mono-shlib-cop.1 mono-xmltool.1 mozroots.1 pdb2mdb.1 permview.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 prj2make.1 resgen.1 secutil.1 setreg.1 sgen.1 signcode.1   sn.1 soapsuds.1 sqlsharp.1 wsdl.1 xbuild.1 xsd.1 mono-configuration-crypto.1 ccrewrite.1   '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man5" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/man/man5"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mdoc.5 mono-config.5 '/usr/local/share/man/man5'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/man'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/man'
Making install in samples
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/samples'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/samples'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/samples'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/samples'
Making install in msvc
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/msvc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/msvc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/msvc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/msvc'
Making install in docs
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && make PROFILE=net_2_0 -f docs.make topdir=../mcs AgilityPack.dll
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: `AgilityPack.dll' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && make PROFILE=net_2_0 -f docs.make topdir=../mcs convert.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: `convert.exe' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
/bin/mkdir -p ./html
runtimedir=`cd ../runtime && pwd`; export runtimedir; \
    cd . && MONO_PATH=../mcs/class/lib/net_2_0 perl ./exdoc -h . ../mono/*/*.c
Merging: mono-api-wapi.html
Merging: mono-api-jitinternal.html
Merging: mono-api-utils.html
Merging: mono-api-types.html
Merging: mono-api-gc.html
Merging: mono-api-class.html
Merging: mono-api-assembly.html
Merging: mono-api-dynamic-codegen.html
Merging: mono-api-methods.html
Merging: mono-api-jit.html
Merging: mono-api-unsorted.html
Merging: mono-api-domains.html
Merging: mono-api-metadata.html
Merging: mono-api-codegen.html
Merging: mono-api-object.html
Merging: mono-api-gchandle.html
Merging: mono-api-marshal.html
Merging: mono-api-type.html
Merging: mono-api-profiler.html
Merging: mono-api-debug.html
Merging: mono-api-image.html
Merging: mono-api-embedding.html
Merging: mono-api-reflection.html
Merging: mono-api-internal.html
Merging: mono-api-security.html
Merging: mono-api-threads.html
Merging: mono-api-string.html
Merging: mono-api-vm.html
Merging: mono-api-exc.html
Merging: mono-api-counters.html
touch deploy/.stamp
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs mono-file-formats.tree
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: `mono-file-formats.tree' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs mono-tools.tree
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: `mono-tools.tree' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && cp -f api-style.css deploy
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs monoapi.tree
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: `monoapi.tree' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
cd . && make PROFILE=net_2_0 -f docs.make topdir=../mcs AgilityPack.dll
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[3]: `AgilityPack.dll' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && make PROFILE=net_2_0 -f docs.make topdir=../mcs convert.exe
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[3]: `convert.exe' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
/bin/mkdir -p ./html
runtimedir=`cd ../runtime && pwd`; export runtimedir; \
    cd . && MONO_PATH=../mcs/class/lib/net_2_0 perl ./exdoc -h . ../mono/*/*.c
Merging: mono-api-wapi.html
Merging: mono-api-jitinternal.html
Merging: mono-api-utils.html
Merging: mono-api-types.html
Merging: mono-api-gc.html
Merging: mono-api-class.html
Merging: mono-api-assembly.html
Merging: mono-api-dynamic-codegen.html
Merging: mono-api-methods.html
Merging: mono-api-jit.html
Merging: mono-api-unsorted.html
Merging: mono-api-domains.html
Merging: mono-api-metadata.html
Merging: mono-api-codegen.html
Merging: mono-api-object.html
Merging: mono-api-gchandle.html
Merging: mono-api-marshal.html
Merging: mono-api-type.html
Merging: mono-api-profiler.html
Merging: mono-api-debug.html
Merging: mono-api-image.html
Merging: mono-api-embedding.html
Merging: mono-api-reflection.html
Merging: mono-api-internal.html
Merging: mono-api-security.html
Merging: mono-api-threads.html
Merging: mono-api-string.html
Merging: mono-api-vm.html
Merging: mono-api-exc.html
Merging: mono-api-counters.html
touch deploy/.stamp
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs mono-file-formats.tree
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[3]: `mono-file-formats.tree' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs mono-tools.tree
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[3]: `mono-tools.tree' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
cd . && cp -f api-style.css deploy
cd . && make -f docs.make topdir=../mcs monoapi.tree
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[3]: `monoapi.tree' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
test -z "/usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources" || /bin/mkdir -p   "/usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mono-file-formats.source mono-tools.source monoapi.source    mono-file-formats.tree mono-file-formats.zip mono-tools.tree mono-tools.zip monoapi.tree monoapi.zip '/usr/local/lib/monodoc/sources'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8/docs'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mono-2.10.8'
[root@***** mono-2.10.8]#
```

I have starred out the server name.

The .net developers have informed me that they cannot get .net to connect and are also clueless as to how to configure Mono. The devs said that when they tried the application, they received an XML result in the browser, which is apparently evidence that Mono isn't working.

Are there any extra steps I need to take to configure Mono further, other than what has been done in the terminal above?

I cannot find any lucid information to aid me in getting this to work and the .net developers seem equally in the dark as to how to go about correctly configuring Mono.

If anyone can guide me on how to get this working that would be awesome :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have installed Mono just fine (although a pretty old version).

My guess is that you have not yet told your webserver (Apache probably) to serve .NET files when asked. For that, you need to install mod_mono.

However, it is a bit difficult to say as you do not specifiy how the Wordpress site calls the .NET code.